# How to check whether a NON blocking exe is complete in java?

Tags: java, command-line, processbuilder

I am running a NON -blocking exe from java using Process builder.Below is my call to run it.

```
Process process = new ProcessBuilder(command).start();
```

It works fine,But i need to read the process output.i can use 
     process.getOutputStream() for blocking calls ,since it is non blocking i am not able to get the output.Is there a way to get it?

Comment: What do you mean by a "non-blocking exe"? Assuming the process is writing to its standard output, `getOutputStream()` should be fine...

Comment: I meant its asynchronous ...so it just runs the process in background thread ,so i dont get any output in getOutputStream()

Comment: No, that still doesn't make sense - if it writes to its output stream, you should see the output in Java. It doesn't matter whether how it does that.